# Let $G$ be any finite group and fix $w\in G$, then calculate the number of pairs $(u,v)\in G\times G$ satisfying $w=uvu^2vuv$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

I have a question about finite groups. This question comes from this PDF [Problems on abstract algebra](https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/18-a34-mathematical-problem-solving-putnam-seminar-fall-2018/resources/mit18_a34f18ps8/).

Here is the question :

> Let $G$ be  any finite group and fix $w\in G$, then calculate the number of pairs $(u,v)\in G\times G$ satisfying $w=uvu^2vuv$.

If we let $uv=t$, the $w=t^2v^{-1}t^2$.  Then we can also calculate the number of pairs $(t,v)\in G\times G$ satisfying $w=t^2v^{-1}t^2$.

But I don't know how to continue about this question.

Any help and advice is greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Letting $uv=t$, we want the number of pairs $(u,t)\in G\times G$ such that $w=tut^2$ i.e. $u=t^{-1}wt^{-2}$. It is the number of choices for $t$, i.e. $|G|$.

Note that your approach worked as well: the number of pairs $(t,v)\in G\times G$ such that $w=t^2v^{-1}t^2$ i.e. $v=t^2w^{-1}t^2$ is also the number of choices for $t$.